# c++ cout string not working. Please advise

Tags: c++, string, cout

I have the below code but for some reason the very last instance (where the noSpaces string should print out) is not being output for whatever reason.

I've already verified that the entire program (excluding that one output string) is working perfectly.

*Note: I am speaking about the line right about `return 0`*

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int countChar(string str);
void removeSpaces(string str);


int main()
{
    cout << "Select a word: ";
    string selectedWord;
    getline(cin,selectedWord);
    cout << "The number of characters in the word " << selectedWord << " is " << countChar(selectedWord) << endl;

    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    string noSpaces;
    while(selectedWord[i]!='\0') {
        if(selectedWord[i]!=' ') {
            noSpaces[j]=selectedWord[i];
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    cout << "The reverse of your selected word is: " << noSpaces << endl;

    return 0;
}

int countChar(string str)
{
    int i=0;
    while(str[i]!='\0') {
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: The program crashed in function countChar. After getline(), your word will be stored into selectword, but it is not ended with '\0'.

Comment: Why not using std::string::iterator ? What's wrong with that ?

Answer (score 1):

This line,

```
noSpaces[j]=selectedWord[i];
```

has Undefined Behavior because the length of `nospaces` is zero: you're indexing storage that doesn't exist.

Replace with

```
noSpaces.push_back( selectedWord[i] );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the modified program:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int countChar(string str);

int main()
{
    cout << "Select a word: ";
    string selectedWord;
    getline(cin, selectedWord);
    cout << "The number of characters in the word " << selectedWord << " is " << countChar(selectedWord) << endl;

    int i = 0;
    string noSpaces= string();
    while (selectedWord[i] != '\0') {
        if (selectedWord[i] != ' ') {
            noSpaces+=selectedWord[i];
        }
        i++;
    }
    cout << "The word without spaces is: " << noSpaces << endl;

    return 0;
}

int countChar(string str)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (str[i] != '\0') {
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

1. To append characters to string, use:

   `noSpaces+=selectedWord[i];`

Comment: There's no need to null terminate a std::string.

Comment: Hey dude, thanks so much.
I used your two lines:
noSpaces = noSpaces + str[i];
string noSpaces = string();
And my program now works!

Answer (score 0):

you did some few mistakes here,you can use string.lenght().  here is the answer

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int countChar(string str);
void removeSpaces(string str);


int main()
{
    cout << "Select a word: ";
    string selectedWord;

    getline(cin,selectedWord);
    int x= countChar(selectedWord);
    cout << "The number of characters in the word " << selectedWord << " is "  << endl;

    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    string noSpaces;
    selectedWord.end();
    for(int i=selectedWord.length()-1; i>=0; i--){
        if(selectedWord[i]!=' ') {
            char c=selectedWord[i];
            noSpaces+=c;
        }
         j++;
    }
    cout << "The reverse of your selected word is: " << noSpaces << endl;

    return 0;
}

int countChar(string str)
{

    int i=str.length();
   /* while(str[i]!='\0') {
        i++;
    }*/
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is tagged C++, so... use it then.
Also there's no need to make a second `std::string`. You don't seem to use the first one again.

```
#include <string>
//#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>


int main(void)
{
    std::cout << "Select a word: " << std::endl;
    std::string selectedWord;
    std::getline(std::cin,selectedWord);
    std::cout << "The number of characters in the word " << selectedWord << " is " << selectedWord.size() << std::endl;

    for (std::string::iterator itr = selectedWord.begin(); itr != selectedWord.end(); ++itr)
    {
        if (*itr == ' ') //0x20
        {
            itr = selectedWord.erase(itr);
        }
    }

    std::cout << "The reverse of your selected word is: " << selectedWord << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

+

```
noSpaces += selectedWord[i];
//or
noSpaces.push_back(selectedWord[i]);
```

Your `std::string noSpaces;` is empty at this place.